# NaN is php output

Tags: php

I am facing a small issue but unfortunately not able to fix it.

```
$rank = 13;  //Sometimes empty or Null
$hits = 3; //Sometimes empty or Null
$rating = $rank/$hits;
if(is_nan($rating)){
  $ratings = 0;
}
if(is_numeric($rating)  ){
  $ratings = number_format((float)$rating, 2, '.', ''); 
}else{
  $ratings = 0;  
}
$res['rating'] = $ratings;
```

I am getting NaN as output if **$rank** or **$hits** are empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cant't by is_nan check the exception ' Division by zero'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you must check the number of $hits to not divide by zero.

```
<?php
$rank = 13;  //Sometimes empty or Null
$hits = 3; //Sometimes empty or Null

function isOkRankandHits($hank, $hits){
    if(isset($hank) && isset($hits)) //Check if hank or hits are not null
    return is_numeric($hits) && is_numeric($hank) && $hits > 0; //OK, you can make the division.
    //You don't specify if hank could have negative values
    return false;
}

$ratings = 0; //for security and maintenance, always work with a default value

if(isOkRankandHits($rank, $hits)){ // ratings will be numeric
$ratings = $rank / $hits;
$ratings = number_format((float)$ratings, 2, '.', ''); 
}

$res['rating'] = $ratings; 
?>
```

Comment: any sample code for the same.

Comment: I've tested with $hank and $hits with numeric, null and string values. For me, this code is working.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$rank = NULL;  //Sometimes empty or Null
$hits = NULL; //Sometimes empty or Null
if(empty($rank))$rank =0;
if(empty($hits)){
  $ratings =0;
} else {
  $rating = $rank/$hits;
  $ratings = number_format((float)$rating, 2, '.', ''); 
}


echo $ratings; 
?>
```

Comment: php can not be divided by zero. you will have an error http://php.net/manual/ru/class.divisionbyzeroerror.php